# Is there any way to remove an app from the most used list on blackberry programmatically?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-jde

I am trying to deploy a monitoring app and was wondering if one could prevent it from showing up in the most used list.

Answer (score 2):

If you extend your app from `Application` instead of `UiApplication` it won't be shown on any home screen at all.